# Error when use vs just-in-time debugger on Firefox plugin-container.exe

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, firefox, npapi, browser-plugin

Does anyone ever use vs just-in-time debugger on Firefox plugin-container.exe?

I want to debug my Firefox plugin on start-up, so I try the just-in-time debugger on plugin-container.exe. I expect once the plugin-container.exe is running, it will trigger the debugger, when I can start VS to debug it.

However, I met the following error, and it happens on each plugin I try to load.

[image: The error dialog pop up when any Firefox plugin is going to load]

What is wrong here? I am using Firefox 23.0.1

Comment: I'm not sure, but maybe the Crash Reporter or other features interfere with the Just-In-Time debugger? Have you tried disabling the crash reporter? Alternatively, try without the Just-In-Time debugger via [the tips here](http://www.firebreath.org/display/documentation/Debugging+Plugins).

Comment: Yes, I've tried to disable the crash reporter as described in Firebreath debugging tips, but issue still happen. But, thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't launch the plugin-container.exe with the JIT debugger; what you can do is connect to it after it launches.  The easiest way to do this is to add a Sleep(10000) in the NP_Initialize or DllMain functions so that you have time to connect the debugger to the process.

As Georg suggested, the tips page he linked to has some other ideas you could use.

Comment: Thanks taxilian, I will try the alternatives. BTW, Do you know the reason why plugin-container.exe can't work with JIT debugger?

Comment: it isn't that the JIT debugger doesn't work, it's that you can't launch it with the JIT debugger because you can't launch it yourself, it has to be launched by FireFox